# Linking the correct variant of an iOS static library using Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have an iOS static library.

As a matter of fact, I have four variants of it:

```
Debug-iphoneos/libopende.a
Debug-iphonesimulator/libopende.a
Release-iphoneos/libopende.a
Release-iphonesimulator/libopende.a
```

I want to link my iOS app against this static library using Xcode.

To do so, I go to **Build Phases**, and in **Link Binary With Libraries**, I click the '+' to add one, using **Add Other**.

Now I have the problem of which variant I should be adding. So I just pick one of the .a files, and hope Xcode is smart enough to find the others?

Anyways, if I do this, the linking fails saying it can't find libopende.a file.

So, is it even possible to do what I want, without first building a 'Framework' instead of a set of static libraries?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so when linking against a static iOS library, you need to know that:

1. It does not matter which .a file you add in the **Build Phases** - **Link Binary With Libraries** panel. Any of the four .a files will do, it only takes the file name, not its path.
2. To actually differentiate between library variants for Debug/Release Device/Simulator, you need to specify the correct library paths in the **Build Settings - Library Search Paths**.

[image: Library Search Paths option]

Comment: Can anyone attest whether this solution should still work in Xcode 11? I have iOS + sim variants of a static lib in different directories. Using this approach of alternate search paths does *not* work - it also requires agreement of the actual .a file linked into the project. My two libs work but I have to uncheck project inclusion for the not-applicable one and check the other to successfully build & run in each case (device, simulator). (Also tried using lipo for universal static lib FWIW, and that only worked for real-ios deivce build, rejected by simulator build).

Comment: Commenting again with the answer for Xcode 11.4+ - the alternate paths will work but you also need some additional steps. 1) give your simulator and runtime libs different names (I used *_sim.a at the end of my simulator libs). 2). Include *all* of them as libraries linked into the project. 3) Under build options Excluded Source File Names, exclude any simulator .a files (using the full file name with suffix) from the from builds of "Any iOS SDK", and similarly exclude the regular iOS .a files from "Any iOS Simulator SDK". With the path variations shown above, this all finally works.